# How to reference a constant in a test in the same lib.rs file in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a constants defined in a lib.rs as follows:

`const GREEN: LedColor = LedColor(0, 255, 0);`

In the same lib.rs file I also have tests trying to use GREEN as follows:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use {OFF, YELLOW, RED, GREEN};
    #[test]
    fn some_test() {//...}
```

But running cargo test gives an error such as:

> no GREEN in path

How do I reference the constant GREEN in a test that's in the same file?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=611742483c6fce155db32f32910b0dad, please include a real[mcve] next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`super`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/super.html) [keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.super.html), to reference the parent module.

The module `tests` is actually `crate::tests`, which means `GREEN` the way you've written it there is really `crate::tests::GREEN`. That doesn't exist, as `GREEN` is defined in the parent module. So you need:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::{OFF, YELLOW, RED, GREEN};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are considered private so a normal `use crate::{names}` wouldn't work.

You can use `use super::*` (`*` makes them all available, as a shorthand) which brings in private names from the parent module. (though this isn't documented from what I could find)

If you don't mind making them public, you can add `pub` and then use `use crate::{names}`.